# How fix Tibco BW Coercion mapping err?

Tags: tibco

I have an anyType element to map to mapper,
But when I follow the instruction to select xsd in left panel "Process Data", I saw a red err in right "Activity Input"

coercion error: The substituted Type "Employee" is not a sub-type of the element's type(Check Coercion List);

This Employee.xsd is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:element name="Employee">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            This generates emp statue change event whenever
            any part of Employees change (retire, resign, leave,)
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="EmployeeID">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        This is the EmployeeID which is equivalent
                        to emp_ID Unique identifier for a specific  Employee;
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

But why it cannot be made coercion??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you try to override an existing element with coercion.
Coercions only work on "any" elements!
Would you mind to upload the actual process where you want to apply this?

Cheers
         Seb